# Cannot create anchors while the camera is not tracking

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

When leaving the ARFragment, and attemping to then resume it.. I guess this issue:

`AR_ERROR_NOT_TRACKING: Cannot create anchors while the camera is not tracking.`

at first I was getting issues about the scene being paused, I was able to get past that error by calling:

`arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().resume();`

However, the camera is not in tracking state apparently. Is there a way to restart that process? I did quite a bit of looking through the docs but couldn't find any sort of method to properly resume camera tracking

Answer (score 1):

In ARCore NDK you'd use the following method for destroying a session and releasing its resources:

```
void ArSession_destroy(ArSession *session);
```

This method releases resources used by an ARCore session. It'll take several seconds to complete. To prevent blocking the main thread, call `ArSession_pause()` on the main thread, and then call `ArSession_destroy()` on a background thread.

Then, you have to create a new session with :

```
ArSession_create();
```

Also, in ARCore Android, there's typically `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods for current session. But I use 2 other ones: `pause(`) for pausing the current session and `resume()` for starting or resuming the ARCore current session.

> Read about `ArSession` methods [HERE](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/session).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Kinda haha.. when i try to use the pause() method in Android.. I get all sorts of errors saying I can't update on a paused session.. I tried commenting out/removing the update loop logic but that dosen't seem to help either

Comment: So don't use `pause` and `resume` then. Use `destroy` and `create`.

Comment: true.. I guess I would have to just keep in a list or something all the placed elements so I can replace them